# How to find neighbors in a grid

Tags: python, function, loops, multidimensional-array

I have to create a function that computes all of the neighbors around a given cell in a grid. Not only that but it must also return all "live neighbors" which are equal to 1 without returning the value of the cell in the middle. I've been reading forums to try and understand exactly how I would do this but I'm still confused.

Here's my code so far with the instructions my teacher gave me:

```
def countLiveNeighbors( grid, rowIndex, columnIndex ):
    # TODO - Find the number of grid rows (HINT: use the len() of the grid)

    rows = len(grid)
    
    # TODO - Find the number of grid columns (HINT: use the len() of the first row)

    cols = len(grid[0])

    # TODO - Compute neighbor indices.
    #        Make sure all indices are positive!
    #        Make sure all indices are not too large!
    r = rowIndex
    c = columnIndex
    for row in rows:
        for col in cols:
            if col >= 0:
               grid[r][c] + 1
            else:
                grid[r][c] - 1
    # TODO - Count the number of live neighbors.
    #        Do NOT count the cell in the middle, only neighbors!


    # TODO - Return the number of live neighbors




# make a test grid to test you function on
testGrid = [[0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0]]


# count the live neighbors for a cell at some row and column
row = 1
col = 2

neighborCount = life_module.countLiveNeighbors( testGrid, row, col )

print( "cell at row", row, "and col", col, "has", neighborCount, "live neighbors" )
```

I'm not understanding what would be the steps I would take to find the neighbors as well as count only the ones that are live. If someone could please explain how its done as well as well as correct my code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's usually best to tag your question with a language. [tag:python]? You can [edit] the question and add a tag.

Comment: ok I tagged it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given some cell `grid[r][c]`, the locations corresponding to up, down, left and right neighbors are `grid[r - 1][c]`, `grid[r + 1][c]`, `grid[r][c - 1]` and `grid[r][c + 1]`. If diagonal neighbors are required, it should be easy enough to figure out what their indices are based on the 4 directions. Obviously you will have to check that the indices are inside the bounds of the array, which can be done by `r in range(rows) and c in range(cols)`.

The code to do so looks like this:

```py
def countLiveNeighbors( grid, rowIndex, columnIndex):
    rows = len(grid)
    cols = len(grid[0])
    r, c = rowIndex, columnIndex
    live_count = 0
    #Coordinates corresponding to up, down, left, right
    dirs = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)] 
    for x, y in dirs: 
        new_r, new_c = r + x, c + y
        if new_r in range(rows) and new_c in range(cols) and grid[new_r][new_c] == 1:
            live_count += 1
            
    return live_count

# make a test grid to test you function on
testGrid = [[0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0]]


# count the live neighbors for a cell at some row and column
row = 1
col = 2

neighborCount = life_module.countLiveNeighbors( testGrid, row, col )

print( "cell at row", row, "and col", col, "has", neighborCount, "live neighbors" )
```

This will output `cell at row 1 and col 2 has 2 live neighbors`. Again, if diagonal directions count as neighbors you will have to add them to `dirs`.

Comment: Ok thanks! quick question though, how would I implement your boundary check into code? would I have to create another function or is there some way to write it in the original?

Comment: @TRNF Edited my answer and updated it to show the code.